# Extract part of a string with regex before hyphen followed by digits

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `test` with a column `category` containing a complex pattern of words, characters and digits. I need to extract words separated by hyphen before another followed by digits into a new column `sub_category`.

I'm not a regex expert and spent too much time fighting it. So will appreciate your help!

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['1','2','3','4'],
    'category': ['worda-wordb-1234.ds.er89.',
    'worda-4567.we.77-ty','wordc-wordd-5698/de/','wordc-2356/rt/']
    })
```

Desired output:

```
    id  category                sub_category
0   1   worda-wordb-1234.ds.er  worda-wordb
1   2   worda-4567.we.ty        worda
2   3   wordc-wordd-5698/de/    wordc-wordd
3   4   wordc-2356/rt/          wordc
```

Comment: you can use this https://regex101.com/r/aUbFUy/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use str.extract,

```
test['sub-category'] = test.category.str.extract('(.*)-\d+')

    id  category                    sub-category
0   1   worda-wordb-1234.ds.er89.   worda-wordb
1   2   worda-4567.we.77-ty         worda
2   3   wordc-wordd-5698/de/        wordc-wordd
3   4   wordc-2356/rt/              wordc
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is simply the start of the string and as many non-digits as possible, except for the final hyphen. This should do the trick:

```
^\D+?(?=-\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zUXDKb/1)

Explanation:

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `\D+?` matches non-digits, but in a non-greedy manner
- `(?=-\d)` matches a hyphen followed by a digit; this forces the previous match to stop.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? This has been tested against OP's requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `split()` also:

```
>>> df
  id                   category
0  1  worda-wordb-1234.ds.er89.
1  2        worda-4567.we.77-ty
2  3       wordc-wordd-5698/de/
3  4             wordc-2356/rt/
```

**Resulted output:**

```
>>> df['sub_category'] = df.category.str.split('-\d+',expand=True)[0]

>>> df
  id                   category sub_category
0  1  worda-wordb-1234.ds.er89.  worda-wordb
1  2        worda-4567.we.77-ty        worda
2  3       wordc-wordd-5698/de/  wordc-wordd
3  4             wordc-2356/rt/        wordc
```

OR , as @jezrael suggested with the split() method with little change specifying the number of split required for the dataset, here its One only ...

```
df['sub_category'] = df.category.str.split('-\d+',n=1).str[0]
```